# Merge statement error when matching on a Masked column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3460.9

When I attempt to merge data from one table with masked data to another table with a masked column I get a primary key violation. The script that is failing for me is in an SSIS package, however I am able to reproduce the same error with the following script as an illustration:

(If running as an admin user you can uncomment the four commented out lines to repro the behaviour)

```sql
-- CREATE USER [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB] WITHOUT LOGIN;

-- EXEC AS USER = '9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB'

drop table IF EXISTS #target, #source

create table #source 
(
    ControlNumber varchar(30), 
    ID char(9) masked with (function = 'partial(0, "XXXX", 4)'),
    primary key (ControlNumber, ID)
) 

create table #target 
(
    ControlNumber varchar(30), 
    ID char(9) masked with (function = 'partial(0, "XXXX", 4)'),
    updated bit default(0),
    primary key (ControlNumber, ID)
)

insert into #target (ControlNumber, ID)
values ('1000001', '234567890'),
       ('1000001', '234567891');

insert into #source 
values ('1000001', '234567890'),
       ('1000001', '234567891'),
       ('1000001', '234567892'),
       ('1000001', '234567893'),
       ('1000002', '234567894'),
       ('1000002', '234567895'),
       ('1000002', '234567896'),
       ('1000002', '234567897'); 

merge into #target t
using (select ControlNumber, ID from #source) as source 
    on t.ControlNumber = source.ControlNumber and t.ID = source.ID
when matched then
    update set updated = 1
when not matched then 
    insert (ControlNumber, ID) values (source.ControlNumber, source.ID);


-- REVERT

-- DROP USER [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB]
```

Running this script produces the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#target___D0BB4E559A6C1F74'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#target'. The duplicate key value is (1000001, xxxx).

Perhaps this is my misunderstanding of how masked columns worked, but running this query against the dat above works as I would expect:

```sql
select 
    s.ControlNumber, s.ID, 
    case 
        when t.ControlNumber is null 
            then 'No Match' 
            else 'Match' 
    end as [matched] 
from
    #source s 
left outer join 
    #target t on t.ControlNumber = s.ControlNumber and t.ID = s.ID
```

Result:

[image]

My understanding is that the purpose of a masked column was to hide the data from unauthorized users, but that joins and matching would work as expected.

Comment: This script I posted does not work on the version of SQL Server I am using (2015), but I confirmed that it does on 2019.  My understanding of masked data is only hidden for display from users who don't have permission. It should not affect joins. etc.

Comment: So this could still be a matter of user privileges?

Answer (score 4):

I've not used DDM but looking at the behaviour of it for this question it looks like a mistake to try and do this operation with a user that does not have permissions to unmask the data.

The simple `INSERT` case below fails too as the data it tries to insert is masked and both masked values are `XXXX7891`. I suppose this makes sense or it would be trivial to defeat DDM.

But anyway I extremely doubt your intention was to insert the actual masked data here rather than the underlying unmasked data.

```
DECLARE @CreateLowPrivUser BIT = 1 /*If you are running as admin set this to 1 as it requires the data to not automatically be unmasked */

drop table IF EXISTS target, source
create table source 
(
    ID char(9) masked with (function = 'partial(0, "XXXX", 4)') primary key
) 

create table target 
(
    ID char(9) masked with (function = 'partial(0, "XXXX", 4)') primary key
)

insert into source 
values ('234567891'),
       ('000067891'); 

IF @CreateLowPrivUser = 1
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB] WITHOUT LOGIN;
    GRANT SELECT ON source TO [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB]
    GRANT INSERT ON target TO [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB]
    EXEC AS USER = '9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB'
    
END

insert into target (ID)
select ID
FROM source


IF @CreateLowPrivUser = 1
BEGIN
    REVERT
    DROP USER [9925FEE6-E584-4CF7-A3FE-A0E017BC29CB]
END
```

With `MERGE` there is a likely bug in that the execution plan shows the masking that is applied is different dependant on whether a `when matched` branch exists or not. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/04x1kL_V) - but either way the value ultimately inserted is masked.

```
--When insert/update branches are present 
DataMask(CASE WHEN [Action1005]=(4) THEN [#source].[ID] ELSE #target.[ID] as [t].[ID] END,
         0x02000000, 
         1, 
         1,
         0,
         0,
         0)

--When only insert branch is present 
DataMask([#source].[ID],
         0x02000000, 
         3, 
         1, 
         0,
         'XXXX',
         4))
```

Per [the answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278213/dynamic-data-masking-issue-when-concatenating-fields/278253#278253) in one case it is applying the partial mask and in the other case the default mask (everything gets masked to `XXXX` - it is not just masking the first 4 characters here).

In 2022 the behaviour with `#temp` tables seems to have changed and the low privileged user sees the unmasked data anyway.

The behaviour for `MERGE` has also changed. The expression in the execution plan when insert/update branches are present is now

```
DataMask(CASE WHEN [Action1004]=(4) THEN #source.[ID] as [s].[ID] ELSE #target.[ID] as [t].[ID] END,
         2,
         0x02000000C2F876A3010000000200000034415FA501000000,
         0x02000000,
         3,
         1,
         0,
         'XXXX',
         4)
```

So the issue with unexpected application of the default mask seems to have gone.